# Make setText of QTextEdit ^Z aware

Tags: qt, qt4, state, qtextedit

When I use QTextEdit::setText()  , changes seems to be inrevokable , you can't get back with `CTRL+Z` , is there any other API I should use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
textEdit->setText("your text");
```

do this:

```
textEdit->clear();
textEdit->append("your text");
```

Answer (score 0):

To support undo/redo functionality properly in your application you may want to take a look at the [Qt's Undo Framework documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qundo.html).